# formulario de google dos preguntas que no tengan las mismas respuestas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Tengo un form de google donde hay dos preguntas. las mismas pregunta sobre que taller se va a inscribir la persona. el problema es que los talleres donde se anotan no puede ser el mismo en la primera y en la segunda pregunta.
El código que estoy colocando es este que se activa con un activador al enviar el formulario.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1uMFKY6Yz0A1A1BkLnVFE7KfpqTOMLIQ5L-E_Y-OQWFY');  // Reemplaza con el ID real de tu formulario
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  
  var respuestaPregunta1 = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var respuestaPregunta2 = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  
  if (respuestaPregunta1 === respuestaPregunta2) {
    // Las respuestas son iguales, muestra un mensaje de error al usuario
    var errorText = "Las respuestas no pueden ser iguales en ambas preguntas.";
    form.setCustomClosedFormMessage(errorText);
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Vpablovv, bienvenido, podrías aclarar que problema tiene el código que presentas, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.